# collision detection not registering with ball

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

Hi I'm trying to make a simple pong game and I'm running into trouble with the collision detection. The ball is not registering with the paddle.

```
    function moveBall() {
    var rightRadius = ballX + radius;
    var leftRadius = ballX -radius;

    if (ballX + radius > canvas.width || ballX - radius < 0) {
        ballOffX = -ballOffX;
    }
    /*
    The following code is handling the collision of the ball with the plate
     */
   if((rightRadius <= (player1.x + paddleWidth))&&(leftRadius >= player1.x) &&(player1.y == ballY + 10)){
        ballOffY = -ballOffY;
    }

    ballX += ballOffX;
    ballY += ballOffY;

}
```

[image]

Comment: player ball plate ? can you show a example image ?

Comment: I renamed the plate to paddle hopefully that helps. Thanks

Comment: you should use vector to  detect collision.

Comment: `player1.y == ballY + 10` is your problem. You probably want an _inequality_, otherwise you're assuming that the ball will at some point be located at exactly that `y` position, which is unlikely given a dynamic velocity.

Answer (score 0):

I made an if statement to sense collisions in JavaScript, here it is:

```
if circle x < rect x + circle width && circle x + rect width > rect x && circle y < rect y + circle height && rect height + circle y > rect y {
```

this works by putting the ball inside of an 'imaginary box' and when any of the edges of the 'imaginary box' touch any of the edges of the rectangle, the collision is detected.